# SQLite - Obtain all dates with maximum version

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this data on my table

DATE        | VERSION

```
"2015-04-01"    |   1
"2015-05-01"    |   1
"2015-05-01"    |   3
"2015-06-01"    |   1
"2015-06-01"    |   2
"2015-06-01"    |   3
```

On SQLite I need obtain the dates and respective version, but only the dates with the maximum version, for example the result of this data must be:

```
"2015-04-01"    |   1
"2015-05-01"    |   3
"2015-06-01"    |   3
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the date to get unique data and then use the `max()` aggregate function on `version`

```
select date, max(version) as version
from your_table
group by date
```